# How do I retrieve camera parameters from a plotly.js 3D plot?

Tags: plot, 3d, camera, plotly.js

I plot 3D scenes from Julia using PlotlyJS into an Electron window. When I change the viewing parameters with the mouse, zooming, panning, or rotating, how do I get the eye, center, and the up vector from the plot? Even when I save the plot into a JSON file, the camera parameters are those of the original plot.

Comment: Any code about what you have done at this moment?

Comment: This is what I did: https://gist.github.com/PetrKryslUCSD/479773bc78dff42830cc829828896d2f

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that the communication between Julia and JS in the plot is one directional. Julia appears never to retrieve the parameters of the plot from JS once it's been created.

Comment: Any idea how to get the json from the actual figure instead of from the Julia code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the options of the plot as

```
options=Dict(:showLink => true)
```

equips the plot with a link to a web site where the plot can be manipulated. The camera settings can be read off there. See, for instance, https://github.com/PetrKryslUCSD/FinEtoolsFlexBeams.jl/blob/master/examples/graphics/edit_plot.jl